# insert multiple records if not exists

Tags: mysql, database, h2

I have a scenario where I need to insert multiple records by checking if the records exists. Each time the server  is started it runs a `sql script`(**.sql file**) which contains `truncate table` statement so the previous rows gets deleted. Is there a way to insert without losing the previous records while running the script and without using the `truncate` statement in the script

```
INSERT INTO employeedetails (EmpNo, FirstName, LastName,DateOfBirth, EmailId, PANNo, PFNumber, BankName, JoiningDate,
    Designation, Location, LOPDays, EmployeeStatus) VALUES
     (1,'A','S','1965-04-14','m@nth.com','ADJP','KN/43708/01','XYZ','2007-10-15','Director','PQR','NIL',1),
     (2,'B','N','1971-01-23','r@nth.com','AAGP','KN/43708/02','XYZ','2007-11-28','Director','PQR','NIL',1),
     (3,'C','S','1982-10-05','d@nth.com','AIBP','KN/43708/03','XYZ','2008-03-17','SA','PQR','NIL',1),
     (7,'D','M','1978-02-17','p@nth.com','AHRP','KN/43708/07','XYZ','2008-07-14','C T O','PQR','NIL',1),
     (8,'E','D','1983-05-12','s@nth.com','BUMP','KN/43708/08','XYZ','2008-05-05','TL','PQR','NIL',1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use **INSERT IGNORE**

> INSERT IGNORE INTO employeedetails (EmpNo, FirstName,
>   LastName,DateOfBirth, EmailId, PANNo, PFNumber, BankName, JoiningDate,
>       Designation, Location, LOPDays, EmployeeStatus) VALUES
>        (1,'A','S','1965-04-14','m@nth.com','ADJP','KN/43708/01','XYZ','2007-10-15','Director','PQR','NIL',1),
>        (2,'B','N','1971-01-23','r@nth.com','AAGP','KN/43708/02','XYZ','2007-11-28','Director','PQR','NIL',1),
>        (3,'C','S','1982-10-05','d@nth.com','AIBP','KN/43708/03','XYZ','2008-03-17','SA','PQR','NIL',1),
>        (7,'D','M','1978-02-17','p@nth.com','AHRP','KN/43708/07','XYZ','2008-07-14','C
>   T O','PQR','NIL',1),
>        (8,'E','D','1983-05-12','s@nth.com','BUMP','KN/43708/08','XYZ','2008-05-05','TL','PQR','NIL',1);

**EDIT** : It worked when Updated the `H2 database` to the latest version and used

**ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**. Sample code:

```
INSERT INTO employeedetails (EmpNo, FirstName, LastName,DateOfBirth, EmailId, PANNo, PFNumber, BankName, 
JoiningDate,Designation, Location, LOPDays, EmployeeStatus, on_duplicate_update_count) VALUES
(1,'A','S','1965-04-14','m@nth.com','ADJP','KN/43708/01','XYZ','2007-10-15','Director','PQR','NIL',1,0),
(2,'B','N','1971-01-23','r@nth.com','AAGP','KN/43708/02','XYZ','2007-11-28','Director','PQR','NIL',1,0),
(3,'C','S','1982-10-05','d@nth.com','AIBP','KN/43708/03','XYZ','2008-03-17','SA','PQR','NIL',1,0),
(7,'D','M','1978-02-17','p@nth.com','AHRP','KN/43708/07','XYZ','2008-07-14','C T O','PQR','NIL',1,0),
(8,'E','D','1983-05-12','s@nth.com','BUMP','KN/43708/08','XYZ','2008-05-05','TL','PQR','NIL',1,0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE on_duplicate_update_count=on_duplicate_update_count+1;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

OR  
 **INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Got Exception `Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT IGNORE[*] INTO EMPLOYEEDETAILS`

Comment: The latest versions of H2 support the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax, but not the `IGNORE` syntax.

Comment: @ThomasMueller thanks buddy just update the version of H2 database and tried with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` did the trick for me.